# When/Where will the planets colide?

Tags: gravity, newtonian-gravity

Given N bodies of known position, mass, speed and direction, if they were to collide, where it will happen and when?

PS: this is not a homework... im working on a physics simulation engine...

**EDIT1:** The bodies interact gravitationally with each other

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no known analytical way to predict this, because the equations are chaotic. So just set up the equations of motion carefully, integrate them properly, and watch what happens. There will be some near misses, and then there will be a collision. You might need to "speed up time" in your model to have it happen in your life time - in a real planetary system this might take many millions of years..

Note that "chaotic" means that even a tiny change in the initial conditions will most likely lead to a completely different evolution of the motion - this is why the best you can hope for is something that "looks life like" rather than something that will predict the actual evolution of say our own planetary system - you just cannot know the initial conditions accurately enough.

But even an approximate solution can be fun to make and observe - you will get a feeling for the kinds of behavior a real planetary system might exhibit.

Paraphrasing the stock market:

"Past orbits are no guarantee of future motion"